# Soql query to check record type

Tags: apex, soql, query, class, record-type

I want to check the record type of Account before doing anything else. I have the following method:

```
    public static void methodName(Id accountId) {
            
            // get account record type
            List<Account> accType = [SELECT Id, RecordType.Name FROM Acccount WHERE Id = :accountId];
            for(Account[] acc: accType) {
                accRecordTypeName = acc.RecordType.Name;
            }
            
            if(accRecordTypeName == 'Patient_Account') {
                // code
            }
  }
```

When I try to save the code, it gives me the following error:

- Variable does not exist: RecordType Line 8
- Variable does not exist: accRecordTypeName Line 8
- Variable does not exist: accRecordTypeName Line 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Salesforce Stack Exchange community...

You have some errors there in your code:

1. You forgot to declare the accRecordTypeName variable...
2. You are querying filtering by Id is not necessary to save
   the query results inside a list, I would recommend you just save
   them in an single SObject not a List of SObjects
3. Normally, its better to use the DeveloperName for validations, this
   value dont gets translated, so normally is a better choice.
4. You wrote A**ccc**ount with 3 c
5. You can use the new safe navigaton operator in case RecordType field is null https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm

```
public static void methodName(Id accountId) {
    
    // get account record type
    Account acc = [
        SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id = :accountId
    ];
    
    if(acc.RecordType?.DeveloperName == 'Patient_Account') {
        // code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the `accRecordTypeName` variable like a String. You should consider doing some trailheads for basic understanding of Apex.